# count the number of fail students by their grade php

Tags: php

I am trying to print out the counter of students by their grade group  for example 
if I have three students between **60 -65**
then print out how many students between **60 -65**

if I have two students between **66 -70**
then print out how many students between **66 -70**

and so on..
I would like to print all the counters for all the if statements.

```
<?php
$numberofstudents = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$counterA=0;
$counterB=0;
$counterC=0;

    if ($grade >= 60 && $grade<=65)
    {
        $counterA=$numberofstudents;
        $counterA++;
        echo "<br />The number of falls by their grade group between 60 and 65 are :   " . $counter6065 ; 
    }
    if ($grade >=66 && $grade<=70)
    {
        $counterB=$numberofstudents;
        $counterB++;
        echo "<br />The number of students by their grade group between 66 and 70 are :   " .                       

        $counterB; 
    }
    if ($grade >=71 && $grade<=75)
    {
         $counterC=$numberofstudents;
         $counterC++;
         echo "<br />The number of students by  their grade group between 71 and 75 are :   " . $counterC ; 
    }
?>
```

My code is not working correctly, when I try to print out `$numberofstudents` is displaying correctly
while the `counterA` is increment whatever value I have in `$numberofstudents`.
Any idea please ?

Thanks

Comment: That is what you're doing in the code. You're assigning the total number of students to $counterA and then incrementing by 1 if the $grade is between 65 and 70. How are you getting $grade? There should be some kind of loop. Post some of the code before the part you have in the question.

Comment: As above, we need to see more of your code. Also, it is likely you can do most of your calculations directly in SQL

Comment: I use a function to calculate the grade.

Comment: The logic for your requirement would say it's one grade per student and as such returned from the query itself and then looped through to make the comparisons, not one grade that is calculated separately.